# Can a View get a result from an Activity?

Tags: android

In an `Activity`, I start an image-choosing activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"), 0);
```

and get the result by implementing `onActivityResult()` in that same `Activity`.

Now I have a custom `View` class, from which I want to do the same thing, or similar.
But I want this class to get the result, and not have to make the parent `Activity` implement `onActivityResult()`, only to hand over the result to my class.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible. `onActivityResult()` always goes to an activity. The activity can delegate that result to something else, such as how fragments can get the results of their own `startActivityForResult()` calls.

(I would further argue that a widget should not be calling `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, as that does not really fit any GUI architecture that I can think of)

Comment: There is one GUI element that does-  a Fragment.  Depending on how complex his logic is, it may make sense to turn the view into a fragment holding a view.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have replaced the Activity in question with a Dialog, which works just fine for the purpose.